# Unit testing of WF code activity

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4

I have created coded activity and now I want to unit test it, but I do not know how.
Any example will be appreciated.

My simple example is below.

```
  public sealed class ParameterActivity : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<int> Argument1 { get; set; }
    public InArgument<int> Argument2 { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<int> Result { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var a = context.GetValue(Argument1);
        var b = context.GetValue(Argument2);

        context.SetValue(Result, a + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have found this link which was well usefull : http://daysincode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/unit-test-of-workflow-for-code-action.html

Comment: That's basically the same think that I showed you in my answer. Just use `CodeActivity<TResult>` to activities with a unique return value. Most do. Then you can easily use `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke<TResult>()` to get the value

Comment: They are also easier to unit test, as you can see by the difference between my code to the blog post's code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, in case your activity returns a single value, just inherit from *[CodeActivity<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465967.aspx)* and easily override *Execute()* with *TResult* as return type. Moreover, you've already available an *[OutArgument<TResult> Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987724.aspx)*.

```
public sealed class ParameterActivity : CodeActivity<int>
{
    public InArgument<int> Argument1 { get; set; }
    public InArgument<int> Argument2 { get; set; }

    protected override int Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var a = Argument1.Get(context);
        var b = Argument2.Get(context);

        return a + b;
    }
}
```

That being said, ***[WorkflowInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx)*** is the way to go to unit test almost all your activities. Taking above custom code activity as example:

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class ParameterActivityTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ParameterActivity_Test()
    {
        var activity = new ParameterActivity();

        var input1 = new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            { "Argument1", 10 },
            { "Argument2", 5 }
        };

        var input2 = new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            { "Argument1", -13 },
            { "Argument2", 3 }
        };

        var output1 = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke<int>(activity, input1);
        var output2 = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke<int>(activity, input2);

        Assert.That(output1, Is.EqualTo(15));
        Assert.That(output2, Is.EqualTo(-10));
    }
}
```

Rather than *[WorkflowInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx)* you can also use *[WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx)* but for unit testing that doesn't seem at all necessary when you just want to quickly invoke short-lived workflows for them to do "their thing" and return. Unless you want to test more elaborate stuff like asynchronous workflows and/or bookmarks.

You'll also want to check ***[Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview)***.

Comment: Be sure to look at How do I use Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting? as well http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20use%20Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview